# Cloud Run restarting issue

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I deployed a simple java spring boot into google cloud run. I tested the api by postman and it worked.

But, If I stop sending requests for 10 or 15 mins, the first request after that causes to restart/start the container.

So, not sure how cloud run is working, but seems after idle timeout it shutdowns the container.

Is this something expected or there is something wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is normal. You are billed when containers are processing requests. Google can shutdown a container when there are no requests.

If you want the container to always run, there is a beta option to enable that `--min-instances`. This will increase your costs.

[Using minimum instances](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/min-instances)

[3 solutions to mitigate the cold-starts on Cloud Run](https://medium.com/google-cloud/3-solutions-to-mitigate-the-cold-starts-on-cloud-run-8c60f0ae7894)

The easiest way to set this option is via the Google Cloud Console. You can also set this option via CLI:

```
gcloud beta run services update SERVICE --min-instances MIN-VALUE
```

Comment: I [wrote an article on this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/3-solutions-to-mitigate-the-cold-starts-on-cloud-run-8c60f0ae7894) recently. And in my tests, I confirm a clean every 15 minutes of idle instances

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere - I updated my answer to include your excellent article.

Comment: But be aware, `--min-instances` doesn't completely solve the problem. Containers can be restarted.  From the Cloud Run documentation: `For Cloud Run services, an idle instance can be shut down at any time, including instances kept warm via a minimum number of instances.`
https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/container-contract#instance-shutdown